# Проектирование отношения руководитель-подчиненный в MySQL

Tags: mysql

Есть такая таблица в MySQL:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
И тут есть отношение "руководитель-подчиненный" между сотрудниками. Сначала я подумал, что есть способ использования внешнего ключа на ту же самую таблицу, и вроде как есть, но это не тот случай.
Можно создать ещё таблицу с названием "Руководитель-подчиненный", в котором будут 2 поля, оба будут содержать айдишники из таблицы `Сотрудники`.
Первое будет означать руководителя, второе - подчененного.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как эта связь будет называться? И что этой таблице предавать? То есть я понимаю, что внешний ключ. Но разве может быть 2 внешних ключа под одному и тому же полю из таблицы `Сотрудники`?

**UPD:**
Собственно, сделал так по наитию.
Но не понимаю:
Что это за связь?
Можно ли так вообще сделать?
Правильно ли, что я указал 2 праймари ключа?
Нужно ли мне было выносить эту связь в отдельную таблицу?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В общем случае возможны любые варианты, включая то, что А является начальником Б по одному направлению работы, и его же подчинённым - по другому направлению. А потому стандартное M:N и несимметричная таблица соответствий.

Answer (score 0):

Такая связь называется many-to-many (многие ко многим), потому что позволяет любой записи (и родительской, и дочерней) иметь произвольное количество связей (в контексте вопроса - первый пример с отдельным полем позволит иметь только одного руководителя, а обсуждаемая many-to-many - произвольное количество руководителей и подчиненных). В вашем случае нет обязательных требований к many-to-many (хватает one-to-many с полем, указывающем на родительскую запись руководителя), но и запретить так делать вам никто не может; кроме того, вынос подобных связей в отдельную таблицу может помочь для облегчения основной таблицы, или при наличии атрибутов у связи (например, если отношения руководитель-подчиненный вмещали еще и характер задач, которые имеет право ставить руководитель, было бы необходимо задать дополнительное поле). В этом случае, впрочем, связь бы уже вырождалась в отдельную сущность внутри вашей системы.

Таблица может иметь сколько угодно внешних ключей на одно поле (ограничение может вносить только формат хранения), с этим никаких преград нет. Первичный ключ в таблице для many-to-many действительно должен состоять из двух внешних ключей, указывающих на связываемые записи.

Comment: Спасибо. То есть я всё правильно сделал? (:

Comment: @VostokSisters по общепринятым правилам не стоит делать лишнего без надобности и стоит обойтись one-to-many.

Comment: А разве я сделал не её?

Comment: @VostokSisters на втором скриншоте many-to-many, а не one-to-many (которая выражается в дополнительном поле связи)

Comment: То есть один внешний ключ можно убрать? Он не нужен?

Comment: @VostokSisters Вопрос не в ключе, а в таблице. Сейчас для любого сотрудника вы можете внести несколько записей с разными начальниками. А верно ли это в вашем случае, может ли быть у одного сотрудника более одного начальника - решать вам. Если начальник может быть только один то дополнительной таблицы быть не должно и внешний ключ должен быть из таблицы сотрудников на нее саму (как вы и предположили изначально). А если начальников у одного сотрудника действительно много - то тогда ваша вторая таблица правильное решение

Comment: @Mike ссылаться на саму себя таблицей не стоит, ведь придется дублировать значения всех остальных полей. Кому это надо? Это глупый подход.

Comment: @VostokSisters Есть запись начальника, у нее свой набор значений полей, есть подчиненный, у него свой набор и в поле id_начальника стоит id собственно его начальника. Что тут по вашему дублируется ? И это не глупый подход, это стандартный и единственно верный подход

Comment: @Mike, а-а-а, точно. Я другую структуру почему-то представил. Действительно, это выход из ситуации. Спасибо.

Comment: @Mike а указывать внешний ключ необходимо в таком случае? Если да, то при поле id (записи) и поле (id supervisor), второе нужно указать как внешний ключ для поля id из этой же таблицы? Опять же, если да, то зачем так делать?... Чисто с точки зрения работы БД

Comment: @VostokSisters `foreign key (id_supervisor) references Сотрудники(id)`. Для того, что бы невозможно было в id_supervisor внести id несуществующего сотрудника или что бы нельзя было удалить начальника, пока на него ссылаются подчиненные

Comment: @Mike ага, теперь понятно. Спасибо. У меня получилась таким образом петля: [скриншот](http://joxi.ru/KAgJkDZf49kW02). Верно?

Comment: @VostokSisters Ну да